# Typescript: Can anyone explain this code block

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand existing code block in a project, I'm a Javascript developer and I'm not aware of TypeScript alot

Code block::

```
ViewModel newPropertyAddress = new ViewModel(){name, previousPro = oldValue }
```

Answer (score 4):

That is not valid TypeScript as far as I am aware. `ViewModel newPropertyAddress` is not how you create a new variable of type `ViewModel` in TypeScript - that would be `const newPropertyAddress: ViewModel`.

To say nothing of the bizarre curly brace block, which is technically speaking valid TS, but I can't imagine who would write any code like that, or why.

Comment: I really appreciate for your help. I got it. I started learning TS, Can you guide me if you can.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I can help you, because whatever language you are using is definitely not TypeScript!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i learned and solved it.

```
ViewModel newPropertyAddress = new ViewModel();
newPropertyAddress.name = getName();
newPropertyAddress.previousPro = oldValue;
```

Thanks for Stackoverflow ComCommunity.